# Why Does Flex Direction Column Disable Top , Bottom?

Tags: html, css

[image: Too Much Space]

I'm trying to adjust the paragraph spacing and move it closer to the title, but Top or Bottom seems to be disabled when using flex-direction: column... What can I do to push up .par2?

Comment: We don't know what code you're using to generate the spacing. Margin, padding? Post some code.

Comment: flex-direction: column is the code I was using... There wasn't a need to post a bunch of code... The answer was given below. Thanks for your input.

Comment: With flexbox. You should be using `gap` to control the gutters between elements.

Comment: Just giving an update, using Gap spaced out all of the elements, and the margin-top gave me control over 1 element.  And by using gap, it disabled margin-top...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties `bottom` and `top` work with `position: absolute;` elements. They don't work with other positions.

You have to use `padding-top` or `margin-top` with negative meaning (for example `-10px`).

And you can check properties `margin` and `padding` by headers ('CATORING', 'EVENT HOSTING', 'DELIVERY') using GoogleChrome Devtools. Most likely it is they who prevent the text from being located higher.